# I need to open a new terminal

Tags: 16.04, java, gnome-terminal, xterm

Is there any java code, which opens up a new terminal in Ubuntu when compiled and run in a compiler ?

Actually, I need to open a terminal from a browser, like when I click on a button from a website then a terminal should be open in my computer system and the operating system would be Ubuntu.

Comment: Offcourse there is.

Comment: Would you please provide me a sample of that program so that I can implement in my project works.

Comment: @An0n Might be, but could be a bit difficult because browsers are usually not allowed to run arbitrary exes on client machines. I would be really, really upset if my browser would run some malicious commands on my PC.

Comment: Thats why i don't gonna post it here. I recommend you to create a downloadable file. Maybe if you show me what you got so far i can give you some more tips.

Comment: I have done far now I am stuck in the function,  how to go to the terminal path and open when button is clicked.         (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E3G2rOn3TMv0kyIfIEEKsL6J6GX7cUvM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the above help, I have successfully solved my problem.